# In R how can I fit multivariative distribution to data and sample from it?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multinomial-distribution, fitting

I collected data on post parcells delivery, each object is a combination of 3 variables:

1. Weight (continuous >0)
2. Destination city (categorial - factor of hundreds)
3. Delivery type (categorial - factor of 3)

I want to fit a multivariative distribution to my data. Later I need to sample data from it for simulation purposes. I use R.

If I undestand things correctly in total continous case one might try gaussian mix or copula approach (using **mixtools** or **copula** R packages)

But my the only continous variable *Weight* is NOT normally distributed and two others are categorial.

**How to deal with this kind of problem?**

Will appresiate any help: general directions in statistics theory or R packages.

**UPDATE**
I have approximately 1 million data rows of each Delivery Type.
Also Kernel density estimation of Weight distribution was made for two major types. So shape of distribution is heavy-tail and slightly depends on Type, for ex. upper chart for Type 1 is a bit steeper:
[image: Kernel density estimation plot]

**UPDATE 2**
I found R package **np** very useful for nonparametric conditional/joint distribution estimation.

Comment: It's not completely clear -- do you want to sample from some fitted model?

Comment: Yes I do. Is it reasonable in case when not so much data will be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how much data you have.  For simplicity let's call weight, city and type $W, C$ and $T$ respectively.  If you have a good amount of data you could fully estimate the dependence structure between these three variables by first estimating the joint probability mass function of $C$ and $T$ (that is, $P(T = t, C = c)$ for every combination of $t$ and $c$), and then the conditional distribution of $W$ for each possible value of $C$ and $T$.  This could be problematic since $C$ can take on hundreds of values and the number of parameters you'd need to estimate is proportional to the number of cities.

The other extreme would be the naive approach of assuming $W, C$ and $T$ are independent, in which case you would estimate all the marginal distributions separately and when you do your simulation you simply draw from each of these marginals individually and combine the results.

My suggestion would be somewhere in between and would again depend on how much data you have as well as which variables you can reasonably expect to have an influence on the others.  I would suspect that $W$ depends more on $T$ than on $C$, so try treating $W$ and $C$ independent but model the distribution of $W$ conditional of the three values of $T$.  You may be able to get away with treating $T$ and $C$ as independent for simplicity's sake.  For the distribution of $W$ some nonparametric approaches would be to use the empirical distribution function (when you sample you just draw from the original distribution with replacement) or a kernel density estimate.  These are nice approaches and quite flexible but require that you "remember" the original data.  To reduce the complexity of your model there's essentially an unlimited number of parametric approaches you can take to density estimation.  Since $W$ is nonnegative you could consider treating it as exponential, log-normal, Pareto, and so on.  It depends on how your data are structured.  Also, does the shape of the distribution depend on $T$?  These are just a few ideas and it's hard to say more without seeing the actual data.

Regarding your question about how to test for dependence between a categorical and continuous variable, this could be approached using an analysis of variance, but unfortunately the ANOVA test itself is unlikely to tell you much about what's going on except in the rare case that you fail to reject the null.  Goodness of fit tests could also be used to test for equality of distributions, but these would suffer from the same shortcomings of the ANOVA test, namely that the null is generally false anyways (but not necessarily in important ways).  It's always a good idea to look at the data, so consider some parallel boxplots to try to visualize how $W$ might depend on $T$, or again check out some kernel density estimates (which I see from your update you've already done).

Comment: thanks for your answer! I updated main question. I have approx.  1M data rows of each Delivery Type. W,C,T definitely are not independent in my case, and since I do not want to simplify model much, so I concentrated on your third idea. How to test mutual influence between categorial and continuous variables?

Comment: ...or 3M data rows are just enough to estimate P(T=t,C=c) first and then conditional distribution of W for each possible value of C and T ? By "problematic" did you mean computational problems or it's again related to the data amount?

Comment: I added a bit more to the post regarding checking for dependence between categorical and continuous variables.  By problematic I mostly mean that the amount of data required could be enormous, and / or you may overfit the data.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation! Finally I ended up with your first idea, got CDF estimation (by using nice  R package: np). The joint distribution of (C,T) first and then conditional of W|(C,T). How to generate new data with estimations I have?

Comment: Could you review the steps please: 1) propose we need to simulate _N_ new data rows, 2) using joint distribution _(C,T)_ I generate matrix each cell of which _(ci,ti)_ contains _ni_ counts and _sum(ni)=N_. 3) for each cell run random number generator _ni_ times to simulate probabilities and use corresponding inverse CDF estimation F_inv(c,t) to simulate value of weight 4) Combine data row as (ci, ti, wi).

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable.